# Generate 2000 6 digits unique numbers with php

Tags: php, random, unique

i am still a Rockie in php and i want to generate 2000 six digits unique numbers.

```
<?php
$six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
print_r($six_digit_random_number);
?>
```

I have written the above simple script which makes sure that the digit is a 6 digit number. Now i need 2000 of them which are not duplicates printed out as an array, how do i go about it?

Comment: Can you tell us more about what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: What does being a Colorado "Rockie(s)" fan have to do with PHP?  "Rookie" maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
<?
// Make an empty array
$numbers = array();

// Loop while there aren't enough numbers
while (count($numbers) < 2000) {

    $random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

    if (!in_array($random_number, $numbers)) {
           // This adds the number to the array
        $numbers[] = $random_number;
    }

}

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number."\n"; // or <br /> if you are using as part of page.
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanx mate this is what i was looking for not sure if the numbers are not duplicates though

Comment: They shouldn't be duplicate, because I only add them to the list if they aren't in it already!

Answer (score 3):

You could go like this:

```
$generated = array();
while (count($generated) != 2000) {
  $new = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
  if (!isset($generated[$new])) {
    $generated[$new] = $new;
  }
}
```

now the `$generated` array contains your 2000 unique random numbers.

Please notice that I saved the number in the array using the number itself as index in order to speed up the lookup to determine if the number is already present.

If you then want a simple numerically indexed array, you could do this transformation:

```
$generated = array_values($generated);
```

but this should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
$randomeArray=array();
while(count($randomeArray)<2000)
{

$six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

if(!in_array($six_digit_random_number,$randomeArray))
   {
     $randomeArray[]=$six_digit_random_number;
   }
}

print_r($randomeArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

This code will be a lot faster than the other examples:

```
$nums = array();
while (count($nums) < 2000)  $nums[mt_rand(100000, 999999)] = true;
```

No need to check to see if a number already exists or not.  Then you can get the numbers by doing:

```
foreach ($nums as $randnum => $val)
{
    // Do something with the random number here.
}
```

in_array() is SLOW.  It iterates over the entire array each time it is called until it finds a match - in this case, the likelihood of a match is slim, so the examples here with in_array() will be a O(n^2) operation.  isset() is a ton faster but not necessary here and count() only takes a slight performance hit as it just measures the size of the array, which is stored in internal PHP data structures.

Hopefully these useful tips will help you as you learn PHP.  Built-in commands like isset() are much faster than functions and it helps to understand which functions are good for what approach along with a healthy understanding of an algorithm's performance.